# Multiple SUM query as 1 row

Tags: mysql

I am using the following SQL to return a couple of sums based on date range:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN omtr_date >= '2013-01-08 00:00:00' THEN omtr_page_view END) AS omtr_page_view,
       SUM(CASE WHEN omtr_date >= '2013-01-02 00:00:00' THEN omtr_page_view END) AS omtr_page_view 
FROM emb_visits;
```

but it returns 2 rows; using `mysqli_fetch_array` (php) it gives me 2 arrays, instead of 1 array with the 2 values in it.

Is it possible to group these 2 results into 1 row/array?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` will always return an array with twice the number of elements as there are rows found (half will be numerically indexed, half indexed with the column name). Try `mysql_fetch_row` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead. Or give up on the `mysql_*` functions and use modern alternatives like MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: @lonesomeday OP clearly states they are using `mysqli_`

Comment: I'm actually using MySQLi, it's mysqli_fetch_array().
I'll try mysqli_fetch_row and see what happens

Comment: Apologies for a reading comprehension failure. (My only excuse is than the `i` is very small :-p)

Comment: Have you tried to change the second column's alias?

Comment: no, how would I do that? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I might change the query so you have different names for each column value you are returning:

```
  SELECT 
      SUM(CASE WHEN omtr_date >= '2013-01-08 00:00:00' THEN omtr_page_view END) AS omtr_page_view_jan08,
      SUM(CASE WHEN omtr_date >= '2013-01-02 00:00:00' THEN omtr_page_view END) AS omtr_page_view_jan02
  FROM emb_visits;
```

By giving different aliases for each column there will be no confusion on what the value is

Comment: It works in PHPMyAdmin as a raw SQL Query, but doesn't work with mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: I'm using :
`
    if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo '<p>'.$row["omtr_page_view"].'</p>';
        }
        $result->free();
    }
`
It works when switching to "omtr_page_view_jan08", but I want to able to receive values from other querys that don't use an alias

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a similar query using other tables? I've done a little example with some tables of one of my databases and it gave me a single row result with 2 columns.

The following is a similar query you could use in the meantime. I promise to edit my answer once I find a solution for your query.

```
SELECT
     (SELECT SUM(omtr_page_view) FROM emb_visits WHERE omtr_date >= '2013-01-08 00:00:00'),
     (SELECT SUM(omtr_page_view) FROM emb_visits WHERE omtr_date >= '2013-01-02 00:00:00')
```

Comment: thanks I tried that but no result

    SELECT
     (SUM(CASE WHEN omtr_date >= '2013-01-08 00:00:00' THEN omtr_page_view END) AS omtr_page_view FROM emb_visits),
     (SUM(CASE WHEN omtr_date >= '2013-01-02 00:00:00' THEN omtr_page_view END) AS omtr_page_view FROM emb_visits);

Comment: Did the other answer work? Gotta say that I've tried yours in a PostgreSQL and it worked fine.